# NetCore app 3.0 and NetStandard 2.1 compatibility issue

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard-2.1

I am referencing a class library project built for netstandard2.1 target by a netcoreapp3.0 project in my Jetbrains Rider IDE and getting a compatibility error. What I understood from .NET implementation support table in the official netstandard dedicated article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) is that they should be compatible. Is my understanding incorrect and is the concept of netstandard different from "standard for building .NET class libraries that should be compatible with both .NET Framework and .NET core"?

Comment: Could you post the exact error message. It could be an incompatibility in c# language version too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Comment: IntegrationTests.csproj: [NU1201] Project UnixUtils is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Project UnixUtils supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)

Comment: There's no incompatibility. You should keep in mind that the Long-Term-Support version is 3.1, not 3.0. 3.0 is already out of support. You shouldn't be using 3.0 for either current or new development. The support lifecycle for .NET Core [was announced years ago](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core), so it was known that 3.0 would be supported for a few months only even before it was released

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely reference a .NET Standard 2.1 project from a .NET Core 3.0 project.

I'm not familiar with Rider, so bear with be, but let's try to see what's wrong:

- Was the dependency added in the right direction? Do you have something like this in `IntegrationTests.csproj`, and not the opposite in the library project file?

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\UnixUtils\UnixUtils.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

- Do you face the same issue when building the .NET Core project from command line (`dotnet build IntegrationTests.csproj`)?

If the anwer to both questions is 'yes', I'm afraid we'll need to see the relevant parts of `.csproj` files to understand what's going on.